# HQL query not working for subtracting column

Tags: hibernate, hql

all I have a table which have one credit column and on debit column I want to sum all debit column and subtract it from addition of credit column. I am unable to do it using hql.

below is my hql query.

```
select debitL FROM ( ("
        + " select eie.trustId as trust_id, sum ( eie.amount ) as sumdr from EntryItemEntity as eie where"
        + " eie.debitOrCredit = 'dr' group by eie.trustId  ) debitL inner join"
        + " ( select eie.trustId as trust_id, sum ( eie.amount ) as sumdr from EntryItemEntity as eie where"
        + " eie.debitOrCredit = 'cr' group by eie.trustId ) as creditL where debitL.trust_id = creditL.trust_id )
```

but I am getting following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 21 [ select debitL FROM ( ( select eie.trustId as trust_id, sum ( eie.amount ) as sumdr from jm.gov.agd.trust.model.EntryItemEntity as eie where eie.debitOrCredit = 'dr' group by eie.trustId  ) debitL inner join ( select eie.trustId as trust_id, sum ( eie.amount ) as sumdr from jm.gov.agd.trust.model.EntryItemEntity as eie where eie.debitOrCredit = 'cr' group by eie.trustId ) as creditL where debitL.trust_id = creditL.trust_id )]
```

please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.